# Deploying ruby-on-rails + angularJS project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Trying to deploy rails + angular project.

**Resolved**: turned out (from browser logs) that:

1) There was small error in one of js files.

2) Main module wasn't loaded because of mess in dependencies, but error message was pinting to one of bootstrap files (?!). Reinstalled twitter-bootstrap gem.

However I still don't understand why project worked in development and didn't worh in production.

Running `rails s -e production`, rails answers normally, renders layout,
assets/javascripts folder is loaded (binded event to window onload - worked) . But all bower plug-ins, incluing angular, jquery etc. not working.
Same issue on local on heroku. Assets are compiled to tmp/... folder. Deploy ends successfully, but angular part doesn't work (no errors in logs), as well as jquery and all plug-ins.

In config/application:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
config.less.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'bower_components')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'bower_components')
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb', '*.eot', '*.svg', '*.ttf', '*.woff', '*.woff2']
```

In config/environments/production:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:mangle => false)
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Tried `bundle exec rake:assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` : does not help.

I think that there is something wrong with loading plug-ins (bower folder, bootstrap, jquery etc.) as main file application.js queried and rendered successfully (logs), but doesn't work as plug-ins seem not found.

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require angular-devise
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-bootstrap
//= require angular-touch
//= require ng-tags-input
//= require angular-loading-bar
//= require angular-xeditable
//= require ng-file-upload-shim
//= require ng-file-upload
//= require Buttons
//= require x-editable
//= require angular-ui-notification
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .

angular.module('boo', ['boo-factories', 'boo-controllers', 'ui-notification', 'ngTagsInput', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'templates', 'Devise', 'ngFileUpload', 'xeditable', 'bootstrapLightbox']);
```

and so on...

Comment: If you open the site in a browser and right-click -> "inspect element" to bring up the console, can you see what assets it is downloading? In Chrome it is under "resources" -> "Frames". You will see entries for "Script", "Style", etc.

Comment: Also are there any errors showing when you use the inspector?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module boo due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'boo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Angular module somehow is not available. Really strange, then why is it ok in development mode...

Comment: check my revised answer @ElizavetaOlehnovich

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that since you are compiling your assets and the way you made the angular app, some of the angular code is spread out and not understood by the asset pipeline, or the browser.

A quick, but dirty solution(since it'll take longer to load the pages) is to:

1. Edit config/environments/production.rb, comment this line:

   *config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier*
2. Clean the asset pipeline in the production environment with:

   *RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean*
3. And finally, start the server again:

   *rails s -e production*

Comment: Of course I'm requiering dependencies. As I said: everything works fine in development mode.

Comment: Could you show us what's in your application.js? @ElizavetaOlehnovich

Comment: As seen from question, compression is turned off. If I'd comment out line with :uglifier files would be compressed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you decided to stick loading up your module in application.js? I would externalize that into another file called app.js and ensure that gets loaded in the tree before your factories, controllers, services, etc.

I would follow the advice given on making sure your assets aren't getting minified in production. That does some weird things.